# Removing index.php from URLS with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an index.php controller what all URLs that aren't existing files redirect to.
The .htaccess rules I currently have look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

# Remove Trailing Slashes
RedirectMatch 302 ^(.*)/$ $1

# Remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302]

# Reroute to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

What I want to do is use a 301 redirect if index.php is included in the URL.
BUT! I can't use RewriteBase or queries that start with a slash because the webapp I'm developing could be in a subfolder. So basically, I only want to rewrite for the current directory:

example.com/foo/index.php/bar/whatever should redirect to example.com/foo/bar/whatever 
example.com/foo/index/bar/whatever  should also redirect to example.com/foo/bar/whatever

localhost/place/foo/index.php/bar/whatever should redirect to localhost/place/foo/bar/whatever 
localhost/place/foo/index/bar/whatever  should also redirect to localhost/place/foo/bar/whatever

How can I accomplish this with .htaccess?

**UPDATED CODE:**
Everything here works EXCEPT:
index.php is not removed from anywhere in the URL.

Here's the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

# Remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Remove Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# Reroute to index.php
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cURL=/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a good idea to mix mod_rewrite rules with mod_alias ones. Try this updated `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

# Remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Remove Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(/.*)?/?$ /$1$2 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# Reroute to index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cURL=/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: With example.com/index.php/foo/ I get example.com//foo/
and with example.com/foo/index.php/foo/bar/ I get example.com//foo/bar/
And without the trailing slash (which the URLs I'm generating do not have) I get a redirect loop.

Comment: See update now, For `http://localhost/foo/index.php/foo/bar` I am getting `http://localhost/foo/foo/bar`

Comment: Make sure this rule is your first rule.

Comment: http://localhost/foo/index.php/foo/bar is getting http://localhost/foo/bar for me with this.

Comment: @rakesh-sharma answer is working, except for removing a trailing slash. If you have any idea how to make this work with his answer:

RedirectMatch 302 ^(.*)/$ $1

Comment: This properly removes the trailing slashes, but doesn't remove index.php from the URL.

Comment: With this, 
http://example.com/index.php/blah/blah => http://example.com//blah/blah and http://example.com/foo/index.php/blah/blah => http://example.com/foo//blah/blah. Also http://localhost/foo/index.php/blah/blah => http://localhost//blah/blah (removing "foo") ...I think we are close! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Did you not write this in your question: `example.com/foo/index.php/bar/whatever should redirect to example.com/foo/bar/whatever` Also your 2nd and 3rd tests cases are contradictory. Both have `/foo/index.php/blah/blah` as source which as per this answer will become: `/foo/blah/blah`

Comment: Yes, that's what it SHOULD be doing. Instead, my local server is going up to the root directory. Localhost/folder/index.php/foo/bar is changing to localhost/foo/bar INSTEAD OF localhost/folder/foo/bar

Comment: And, on my live server example.com/folder/index.php/foo/bar is redirecting to example.com/folder//foo/bar... How do I get rid of the extra slash?

Comment: Most likely on your localhost you don't have this .htaccess in `DocumentRoot` Also see updated code.

Comment: What would be the easiest way to specify that the rules should only apply to a subdirectory? I'm assuming I could write it into the last two rewrite rules somehow. It's not really NECESSARY but it would be nice to know.

Comment: Simply place these rules into `/subdir/.htaccess` to make sure rules apply only to that subdir and below paths.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have mod rewrite on on your server try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This seems to work for everything...except removing trailing slashes. I get a query string of the same URL when it removes a slash. IE: example.com/test/123/456/ becomes example.com/test/123/456?/test/123/456/

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```